How to implement sampling for imbalance data?
I'm currently working on a multi-label image classification problem where my dataset is significantly imbalanced. Each image in my dataset can have multiple labels. The labels are provided in a one-hot encoded format. For example: [1,0,0,0,0,1,0] etc.

Shape of train images: (15243, 256, 256, 3).
Shape of train labels: (15243, 13).
Shape of val images: (1455, 256, 256, 3).
Shape of val labels: (1455, 13).

My code:
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_sample_weight
train_sample_weight = compute_sample_weight(class_weight='balanced', y=train_labels)
train_sample_weight

How to pass it to model.fit(). Moreover is this right way of balancing the data using sklearn or I am doing something wrong ?
